# c3p0 Connection Software caused connection abort: recv failed error

Tags: jpa, jta, c3p0

My Connection properties are given below

- jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://db_host:db_port/db_name
- jdbc.driverClassName=db_driver_class_name
- jdbc.username=db_user
- jdbc.password=db_password
- jdbc.hibernate.platform=hibernate_dialect
- jdbc.initialPoolSize=25
- jdbc.minPoolSize=25
- jdbc.maxPoolSize=500
- jdbc.checkoutTimeout=1000
- jdbc.acquireRetryDelay=1000
- jdbc.acquireRetryAttempts=30
- jdbc.acquireIncrement=50
- jdbc.breakAfterAcquireFailure=true
- jdbc.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true

  occasionally i got the following error

  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:74)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:197)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:566)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:802)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1203)
  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)

  after that it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unlikely to have much to do with the connection pool. It's a network / JDBC driver issue. In particular, you might want to look for Oracle bug 9373409 -- see https://forums.oracle.com/message/9176463#9176463 https://forums.oracle.com/message/10332437#10332437 If that is your issue, you may want to upgrade your Oracle installation, bug 9373409 was supposed to have been fixed as of "Patch Set" 11.2.0.3, see http://www.eygle.com/Notes/11203_buglist.htm